Run libraries outside docker within same server
I am new docker and cant find any relevant information about docker application that can utilize libraries outside the docker it self. For example:
I use the following libraries in the nodejs script:

GraphicsMagick
perl-Image-ExifTool
ghostscript
optipng
qpdf
google-chrome

Wouldnt this be bloated as having multiple containers with the same libraries over and over?
Is there a tutorial that explain the best way to pack this libraries in a docker container?

One of the major points of Docker is that an image is self-contained.  You should be able to run an image on any system that has a suitable container engine, whether that's a full desktop OS or a minimal distribution on a dynamically-created Kubernetes node.  The image should work the same way regardless of what the host has installed.
In short: you can't (*) depend on libraries or binaries on the host.

Wouldn't this be bloated?

There's an argument that it's wasteful.  (This is more visible with really huge packages like Libreoffice, TeXLive, or PyTorch.)  One thing to remember is that the container shares most of its filesystem with the image, so if you run 6 containers from the same image, it won't usually actually take up more disk space.
Docker's layer system can help, if you have multiple applications with similar dependencies.  Images share layers too, so if you have multiple images that start with the same base then they'll share space.  For example, if you have
FROM some-language-runtime:debian AS dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install ...

FROM dependencies AS app-a
COPY ...
RUN ...
CMD app-a

FROM dependencies AS app-b
...
CMD app-b

and you build both the app-a and app-b images from it, the two images will share the base image and the base layer that installs the OS-level dependencies.  (This may depend some on your specific Docker build engine setup and may not survive being pushed to a repository.)
(*) In principle it's possible to inject whatever you want from the host system using bind mounts.  Most applications aren't single binaries, though, so you'd need to make sure you get C shared libraries, fonts for Ghostscript, internal Javascript support code for Chrome, downstream dependencies for the Perl library, and so on.  You'd also need to track these down to individual files, and hope that file location doesn't change with OS updates.  If what you're trying to inject is a single statically-linked binary then it could work, but it's still not a best practice and I wouldn't try it.
